# get rid of ContentProvider per database table

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

In my (Android) project we have an `ContentProvider` per database table.
Every `ContentProvider` extends AbstractContentProvider, which has some virtual methods which gets some information about the database table (e.g. the table column names). Thanks to this, we can have some nice checks during insert/delete/etc operations on each table `ContentProvider`.

But on the other hand, adding a new database table consists of writing a lot of redundant code - after writing a schema we need to create a `ContentProvider` with analogous among different tables methods and add it to the manifest.

We would like to get rid of this boilerplate and to be able to retain current behavior. Can this be done? A solution we thought we'd use was to first change all `ContentProviders` AUTHORITIES to the same one and register only one `contentProvider` in manifest, but this apparently is not possible.

Do you have any other ideas to achieve this goal?

Comment: "A solution we thought we'd use was to first change all ContentProviders AUTHORITIES to the same one and register only one contentProvider in manifest, but this apparently is not possible" -- sure it is. That's how the vast majority are implemented. You would need to use different `Uri` structures for each table (e.g., `content://.../foo/...` maps to the `foo` table), perhaps using a `UriMatcher`. The `ContentProvider` you put in the manifest then either handles it all itself or delegates to other per-table objects for table-specific operations.

Comment: this https://github.com/njzk2/SimpleStorage/blob/master/SimpleStorage/src/com/njzk2/simplestorage/DataProvider.java is a typical implementation of a ContentProvider that serves any table without any prior knowledge of those tables. Adding a table or modifying a schema does not require any modification in the ContentProvider

Comment: @CommonsWare - you mean that every table has its own entry in `UriMatcher` and there is a big switch that takes care of changing `UriMatcher` value to table-class object, that takes care of the table-specific operations? It doesn't sound perfect (due to the switch), but anyway it's much better then what we have now. Thanks ;)

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

you should ideally use single content provider and expose multiple URIS - one for each table.

Implementation for CRUD methods for all the URIs are similar and can be done in a generic way. No code duplication is required to handle multiple URIs. Reason being SQliteDatabase has similar APIs/parameters that maps with ContentProvider API parameters